# No margin on small device

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive, margin

I have a simple layout like this
[Layout1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZMpU.png)
I use margin-right and margin-left auto to align it.
It looks fine, but I simulated a mobile Phone and if the screen size is small this can happen:[Layout2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Czt8.png)
I know it´s possible to make a responsive design with @media or viewport, but is there another option which makes more sense in my case?

Comment: Without code, it's difficult to help. Please share a snippet

Comment: #header { 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
margin-top: 20px; 
width: 950px;
height: 199px;
border: 4px solid; 
background-image: url("Header.png");
} #wrapper {
width: 880px;
height: 900px;
background-color: #CF5837; 
border-left: 2px solid;
border-right: 2px solid;
border-bottom: 2px solid;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
margin-bottom: 10px;

}

Comment: Can you please upload your code to code sandbox or something like that, so that it's easy to solve the issue?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0yL4uQ2H